# Using Physics Editor and using it's .plist Cocos2d-x V3 for better collision detection

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I was working on a cocos2d-x project. Its a simple game. Everything is working right apart from collision. Though, It is working but collision is not very realistic. I browsed and discovered something called - Physics Editor. I read tutorials from - http://www.codeandweb.com. It generates a .plist of your sprite. I'm making game for android in c++.

Now the problem -

How to use that .plist with cocos2d-x V3.8. Is it a good idea to make collision detection better this way?

I want to start with box2d and chipmunk but there are no good and new tutorials. In case you have anything, Feel free to suggest. Thanks is advance !

Comment: for some reason, unknown, physics are barely discussed. I think most of the people that use them know them. And they are not many people.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Physics Editor itself provides special C++ class for loading its plist and creating PhysicsObjects from it.

You can easily get it on github: https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/tree/master/cocos2d-x